# Twitter profile widget

Tags: twitter, widget

I'm using the twitter profile widget on my website.I changed the settings as i want,got the code from twitter site. https://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_profile

The problem with this widget is ,each time it want me to refresh the page to see the tweets.

I want to load the tweets with out refreshing the page. Is there any way,i implement this on my widget.

```
<script charset="utf-8" src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 4,
  interval: 30000,
  width: 250,
  height: 300,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#333333',
      color: '#ffffff'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#000000',
      color: '#ffffff',
      links: '#4aed05'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: false,
    live: false,
    behavior: 'all'
  }
}).render().setUser('twitter').start();
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force this widget to load new tweets with `live` parameter set to `true`. Change it in your script or grab a new one at https://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_profile and make sure you check `Poll for new results?` in `settings` tab.